# "Missing manifest" error at $ rkt run

Tags: rkt, appcelerator

I have the following shell script which creates a Debian base `aci` container for `rkt` / `appC`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# $ zcat debian.aci | tree | head
# $ rkt run debian.aci --insecure-options=image

export MY_CHROOT=/var/lib/container/aci/debian

mkdir -p $MY_CHROOT

debootstrap --verbose --arch=amd64 --include=iputils-ping,iproute --variant=minbase stable $MY_CHROOT/rootfs http://httpredir.debian.org/debian

cat > $MY_CHROOT/manifest <<EOF
{
  "acKind": "ImageManifest",
  "acVersion": "0.8.9",
  "name": "debian",
  "labels": [
    {"name": "arch", "value": "amd64"},
    {"name": "os", "value": "linux"},
    {"name": "version", "value": "1.0.0"}
  ],
  "app": {
    "exec": [
      "/bin/sh",
      "echo",
      "Hello, World from $MY_ENV_VAR!"
    ],
    "user": "0",
    "group": "0",
    "environment": [
      {
        "name": "MY_ENV_VAR",
        "value": "$(whoami)"
      }
    ],
  },
  "annotations": {
    "authors": "Istvan Lantos <email@addess.com>"
  }
}
EOF

# use gpg to create a sig, but we'll skip that for now
tar cvvf - $MY_CHROOT/manifest $MY_CHROOT/rootfs | gzip -c > $MY_CHROOT/debian.aci
```

To verify that `manifest` file is present:

```
root@debian:/var/lib/container/aci/debian# zcat debian.aci | tree | head
.
├── debian.aci
├── manifest
└── rootfs
    ├── bin
    │   ├── bash
    │   ├── cat
    │   ├── chacl
    │   ├── chgrp
    │   ├── chmod
```

When I try to run this container with `$ rkt run debian.aci --insecure-options=image` command, I got the following error:

```
run: missing manifest
```

I followed these guides for file structure:

https://github.com/appc/spec

https://github.com/appc/spec/blob/master/spec/aci.md#image-layout

https://github.com/appc/spec/blob/master/examples/image.json

Why not working?

Thank You for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the error is caused by `tar` which includes absolute paths in the archive.

So solution is to `cd` in the directory and not use absolute paths prefixed by `$MY_CHROOT`.

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/59246/120771